# What is the difference between "who packed my chute?" and "who has packed my chute"?

Tags: past-tense

I really can't feel difference between past simple tense and present perfect in that case. Example is the excerpt of dialogue from the Point Break film:

> -This is a ceremony we always do at the end
>   of the summer. One last speed star.
>   By the way, you might wanna pull
>   that orange thing sometime.
>   The life you save may be your own.
>
> -So, uh...who packed my Chute?

What would it have changed in meaning, if the protagonist had said "who *has* packed my Chute"?

Comment: I don't see how your title applies to the quote you provide. Please explain what you are asking with respect to the quote. "who have packed chute" is not correct, not clear what you intend here.

Comment: Neither version in the question title (ie “who packed chute?” and “who have packed chute”) works. The word "my" as in the quotation is needed.

Comment: @djna Firstly, i've mistaken about past perfect, I meant present perfect actually. Then, I can't figure out why "who have packed chute" is not correct. Isn't Present Perfect tense looks like "I've seen that", "I've packed my chute", "Who have packed the chute"? Is my mistake about article?

Comment: @djna Title is the question itself - for you, what is the difference between Past simple and Present Perfect in case of film dialogue. How much the phrase "who have packed my chute" is different to original phrase?

Comment: In case it's not clear: The chute is the thing that saves your life if you jump from a plane (parachuting). A chute is a countable thing. For uncountable things, you can say for example "I drink milk" without any counting or other word attached. You can't say "I carry chute". You can say "I carry a chute", "...the chute", "... two chutes", "... my chute". Similar, "who packed chute" or "who have packed chute" are wrong. You could say "Who packed the chute" or "Who packed my chute". But "Who have packed my chute" is still wrong, it's "who has packed my chute".

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks for clear explanation. Now I understand I've mistaken with the article (just forgot about it) and that we add S to the end of the verb in the 3rd person. I should say that article usage is a real nightmare for russian english learners sometimes. Anyway, my question is regarding difference of meaning of two similar (in my opinion) tenses - past simple and present perfect, not that nasty mistakes I could make and made. Thank you ;-)

Comment: @AlanCarmack You reffered me to the question, where the first answer begins as "Context, context, context! The choice between present perfect and past is governed primarily by how it fits in your discourse.". That's why I've given you an example of context to help me choise right tense and explain a bit why should I use either one.

Comment: jumpjet67 Even though you have provided a context, the answer of @StoneyB starting "Context,  context  context" seems to me to provide the information you need to decide between the two tenses. If it is not clear how that is the case, please edit your question and explain. It's  better to do this in your question than in these comments.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I'm sorry if I tired you with my stupidity. I would edit my question if I known how to make it more clear. Figure someone asking "Who has packed my chute?" or "Who packed my chute?" - I just want to know if this two sentences have different meaning in my context or no?